# meld -- How to refresh display when you have changed one of the files

Tags: meld

I'm using Meld 1.8.5.
http://meldmerge.org/

I use gedit to change a file without meld's knowledge.  I like to re-do the comparison.  What is the easiest way of doing the refresh.  The refresh didn't do the re-comparison.

Robert

Comment: the question is valid and I haven't find a way to do it, but the question belongs to superuser I guess!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So for newer version of Meld, File/Revert does the requested refresh.

Answer (score 2):

In Meld's View menu, you can try Refresh (Ctrl+R), but also Reload (Shift+Ctrl+R) to reload the files themselves. Depending on the changes, you may want to try the Reload option. Also, be sure to have gedit make a save to disk in order for Meld to see the change of file contents.

Comment: In some cases Refresh doesn't work and it doesn't automatically notice either. And there's no reload in some versions.

Comment: Which version are you using? I'm using meld 3.18.0-6 from Ubuntu 18.04 repository and there is no reload option. Reload was at older versions https://superuser.com/a/629711/173871